# SocketIO Android not emitting connection event

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm using [Android native socketio library](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) and NodeJS.

```
    // on my Android activity
    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://IP_OF_MY_SERVER");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSocket.connect();
    }
```

.

```
// on my nodejs app
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'myapp',
  version: '1.0.0'
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server.server);

server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('new-item', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

I'm following official guides but still `mSocket.connect()` not emitting `connection` event and there is no `a user connected` on my console when I launch activity.

Can you please tell me what is I'm missing and how can I debug it?

---

**EDIT**

NodeJS app on my Ubuntu server : http://paste.ubuntu.com/14233470/

Android activity : http://paste.ubuntu.com/14233482/

---

**EDIT 2**

I've changed my code like suggested [here](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#socketio):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

And this time I'm getting this error when I launch the activity

myapp listening at http://104.131.99.145:3000

```
http.js:691
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    at ServerResponse.format (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/response.js:145:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/response.js:338:14)
    at emitRouteError (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:201:13)
    at onRoute (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:754:21)
    at Router.find (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/router.js:608:5)
    at Server._route (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:747:21)
    at routeAndRun (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:705:14)
    at Server._handle (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:725:9)
    at Server.onRequest (/var/www/biditapi.erayalakese.com/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:326:14)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

Comment: First you should start by establishing a connection to the *Node.js* server. Do you get that toast that says **"cannot connect to server ?"** (like, each 2 seconds)

Comment: @Sparta no I didn't get any Toast message. I'm debugging Android app and *mSocket* variable is set.

Comment: Did you create & run a **local** Node.js server ?

Comment: Yes I'm running script with `node api.js` command on my server.

Comment: Delete that call to `next()` after calling `res.end(data);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few key notes:

1. Create a `Socket` object:

   ```
   private Socket mSocket;
   {
       try {
           mSocket = IO.socket(CHAT_SERVER_URL); // Your server's URL
       }
       catch (URISyntaxException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }
   ```
2. `onCreate()`: connect & set the socket error **listener**

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
       mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
       mSocket.connect();
   }


   private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
       @Override
       public void call(Object... args) {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect to NodeJS server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           });
       }
   };
   ```
3. **Disconnect** the Socket in the `onDestroy()` method

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();

       mSocket.disconnect();
       mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
       mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
   }
   ```

Not getting the error toast is the first milestone to setting this up right.

4. Create a **WLAN**:

> (Open the command line with admin privileges, run these commands:)
>
> **netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NodeSocket key=1234okok**
>
> **netsh wlan start hostednetwork**

[image: WLAN]

Make sure that your **Android** device is connected to this network, & that your `Node.js` server is up & running.

Comment: *Unable to connect to NodeJS server*

Comment: That's a start.. you need to provide more code, more infos on your configurations.

Comment: Make sure that you added the **INTERNET** permission to your manifest.

Comment: my server is Ubuntu so I don't have `netsh`  command. I'm now editing my question to provide full codes.

Comment: please check my **EDIT 2**

Comment: Just solved problem with your helps. I'll write the solved one hour later. Thank you so much.